# RAW image rotated by wrong angle in WPF image control

Tags: c#, wpf, rotation

I have an image viewer written in C#, WPF, .NET v4. It reads the orientation EXIF tag and rotates accordingly the displayed image. It works great for JPGs. When loading RAW formats supported by the camera codec pack (NEF and CR2, in my case) the rotation is correct only for 0 and 180 degrees, for 90 and 270 the image is rotated by 180 degree (ie. upside-down, not portrait). 
The code for rotation is (`imgOrientation` below is correct):

```
img.LayoutTransform = new RotateTransform(imgOrientation);
```

Windows Photo Viewer shows OK.

Is somebody aware of this problem, any solution?

Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Sounds to me like the direction of the rotation angle used by NEF and CR2 is opposite of what is expected by RotateTransform. Perhaps you could try to send in `360 - imgOrientation` instead of just `imgOrientation`?

Comment: my initial description wasn't clear, 90 and 270 aren't interchanged, the picture is upside-down (as rotated by 180) - edited

Comment: So it's not rotated by 90 degrees, then rotated by 180 degrees, but it's actually rotated by 180 degrees Instead of being rotated by 90 degrees? Have you checked the actual value of imgOrientation? And how do you obtain the value from the image?

Comment: Exactly. The orientation tag is correct (checked in debugger and displayed in the app), obtained with exiftool. Photoviewer and irfanview show it correctly, so the photos are ok as well.

Comment: Hm.. And what happens if you don't apply the Rotate Transform? Could it be that perhaps the image contain internal rotation logic?

Comment: You're right! It seems that camera codec pack decodes RAWs auto-rotated for 90 and 270 but not for 180 degrees, so I have to apply my rotation only for JPGs and RAWs for 180 degrees. Thanks